# Is there any possibility for saving or caching form datas in jsp

Tags: java, session

Came across a situation where I have to save data s , scenario is in an application there are 5 different forms and user needs to fill all the forms, after filling 4 forms the user leave it for some time so that the session is expired in this case he needs to fill all the forms from the beginning. Is there  any way so that all the form data s he filled will be saved or cached so that he only needs to fill the remaining form.

Thanks.....

Comment: have you thought about saving the form data in a cookie?

Comment: No, I want to save the state of the object so when the user enters second time he does not have to go through all the forms, he can start from the unfilled forms.

Comment: store it in a lookaside cache, and retrieve based on a primary key in the cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can store data in cookie . u can use http://www.jstorage.info/ for storing data .

Comment: I saw the link provided by you, but checkout the browser supports.